# open input file with default name

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How to put the name of a file automatically when opening an input file? so that when opening the file browser it automatically searches for a file called namedefault.xml for example.

I have my code in VUE, it is the following:

```
<v-col cols="12" sm="6" >
   <v-file-input ref="filexml" dense outlined required :label="t.uploadXML" accept=".xml" small-chips truncate-length="13" v-model="filexml" :rules="rules.filexml"></v-file-input>
   <v-spacer></v-spacer>
   <v-file-input ref="filepdf" dense outlined required :label="t.uploadPDF" accept=".pdf" show-size small-chips truncate-length="13" v-model="filepdf" :rules="rules.filepdf"></v-file-input>
</v-col>
```

when opening filexml I want the search box to open as in the following image:
[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vL5wK.jpg)